# A Closure Cannot Call Any User-Defined Function in CF 10? why?

Tags: coldfusion, closures, coldfusion-10

> ***Note:*** A closure cannot call any user-defined function, because the
>   function's context is not retained, though the closure's context is
>   retained. It gives erroneous results. For example, when a closure is
>   cached, it can be properly called for later use, while a function
>   cannot.

Quoted from: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d31851842acbba1353e848b35-7ffa.html

Would someone please elaborate on this?  Why can't closure call UDF's?

Can closure can call CF built-in functions? or just User-Defined functions?

I think understanding the limitation of this is crucial.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closure can call both CF built-in functions and User-Defined functions. There is no limitation whatsoever with CF's implementation and you can try yourself to verify the same.

The doc note present is because of a bug logged (with prerelease) that a cached closure instance (say in application scope) was not able to cal UDFs when executed twice. I believe it was fixed and hence the note should be removed.

p.s. I worked on closure's implementation in ColdFusion

Comment: awesome, can you please notify the documentation ppl to update it?  Thank you!

Comment: Chandan, would you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604166/how-to-scope-closures-variables-in-cf10/10614244?  Love to hear your input on this.  Thank you!

Comment: @Henry Thanks for bringing it up! It is indeed misleading in docs, will notify the team.

Answer (score 0):

> A closure retains a copy of variables visible at the time of its creation.

This is basically the definition of a closure in computer science. A captured environment and some code to evaluate in that context.

The restrictions on calling functions from closures appears to be a bug in the implementation of closures in ColdFusion -- functions being unable to access their environment, from the environment captured by the closure.